# Input C++ Vector into C function

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a `std::vector<float>` containing sound data. Without copying its data, I'd like to use this vector as input to the [sonicChangeFloatSpeed](https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic/blob/master/doc/index.md#using-libsonic-in-your-program) function of the Sonic library. This method expects a `float*` as first argument and mutates the input array. After completion, the pointer in first argument would point to the result data.

[`data`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) gives me access to the internal array of a C++ vector and with [`assign`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/assign/), I can replace the vector's contents. Hence, I tried the following:

```
float* ptr = vec.data();
int num_samples = sonicChangeFloatSpeed(ptr, vec.size(), 1., 1.5, 1., 1., 0, 41000, 1);
vec.assign(ptr, ptr + num_samples);
```

But when I run this program, I get the error `double free or corruption (!prev)` with a `SIGABRT` at this location. What is the problem of this approach and how would this question be solved more appropriately?

Comment: The doc says it modifies in place so `assign` shouldn't be needed. Try `vec.resize(num_samples);`. If you were slowing the sample down - and therefore the function will require a larger buffer - you would also want to call `resize` before the function  as well.

Comment: `vec.assign(ptr, ptr + num_samples);` this is probably not needed - what does value of `num_samples` mean with respect to a `float` ?

Comment: `vector::assign` with a pointer to data in that vector has undefined behaviour. (The vector most likely frees its memory before copying the data.)

Comment: Any elements held in the container before the vector::assign call are destroyed and replaced by newly constructed elements. If you assign the same data you just destroyed, you have a problem.

Comment: [A good reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign#:~:text=The%20behavior%20is%20undefined%20if%20either%20argument%20is%20an%20iterator%20into%20*this.) should have mentioned that :) (This is the reason why I let cplusplus.com down for cppreference which is more complete and accurate).

Comment: I think what you were trying to do with assign is just reduce the vector size. Change it to vec.resize(num_samples);

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I guess, if the method changes the position of the input data (re-allocates new memory), the pointer inside the vector is changed as well? Unfortunately, using `resize` does not solve the problem at hand, but I also might have misidentified the problematic area, if this code above is otherwise ok (after `s/assign(ptr, ptr + /resize(/`).

Comment: I have solved this problem by not using `sonicChangeFloatSpeed`. I basically used the code within `sonicChangeFloatSpeed`, but do `vec.resize(numSamples)` before reading the result from the stream into `vec`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned, I solved this problem by not using `sonicChangeFloatSpeed` at all, but the code within it. Before reading the results from the stream into `vec`, I do `vec.resize(numSamples)`:

```
sonicStream stream = sonicCreateStream(16000, 1);
sonicSetSpeed(stream, speed);
sonicSetPitch(stream, pitch);
sonicSetVolume(stream, volume);
sonicSetRate(stream, rate);

auto length = static_cast<int>(vec.size());
sonicWriteFloatToStream(stream, vec.data(), length);
sonicFlushStream(stream);
int numSamples = sonicSamplesAvailable(stream);
vec.resize(numSamples);
sonicReadFloatFromStream(stream, vec.data(), length);

sonicDestroyStream(stream);
```